# Missing color code in Visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Hi i am missing the color code of my web.config files in Visual studio 2008 SP1
how do i get it back

you can se it here [link text](http://i27.tinypic.com/akwy1e.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be in Tools > Options > Text Editor, in one of those settings. Probably "XML" or "XAML".

I'll have a closer look and update this if and when I can be more precise :-)

Answer (score 1):

base on your answer i was able to find it is XML and it is a error en the formating 
i can be repair with 
%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /setup

Comment: Ah, you found it before I did then. Glad that you sorted it out :-)